# Apply colormap to 2d array without the countour effect

Tags: image, matplotlib, colormap

I'm able to generate a pure image applying a desired colormap to a 2D array, without passing to matplotlib (this makes things faster).
The current working method is

```
myarray = # a 2d numpy array
cm = plt.get_cmap("twilight")
image_tmp = np.uint8(cm((myarray - min_val) / (max_val - min_val )) * 255)
pil_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(image_tmp)
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img("Wigner_Unique.png", pil_img)
```

which gives the following figure:

[image: with contour effect]

As you can see a little contour effect is present, while if I make that image with matplotlib

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi = 150)
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, myarray, cmap = "twilight")
```

the image is clear, without that bad effect:

[image: without contour effect]

How can i get a more clear image with the first method (which is much faster)?